# Unable to find container from item in Treeview

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I got an `ItemsControl` (a `Treeview` or a `TreevieItem`) wich `Item` is filled with my own Model.

I wan't to programatically unfold the `TreeView`. So I try this:

```
var model = itemsControl_.Items.Select(i => i as MyModel).Where(ftn => ftn != null && ftn.key = searchedKey));
```

now that i have founded the model a want to unfold. I search for the container to unfold it:

```
var tvi = itemsControl_.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(model) as TreeViewItem;
 if(tvi!=null)
 {
  if (!tvi.IsExpanded)
  {
   tvi.IsExpanded = true;
  }     
 }
```

And sometimes `tvi` is null !?!

Can someone explain me how that can be possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it seems you want to expand TreeViewItem.
   I think this is most likely caused by the Virtualizating. The Virtualizating Attached Property is on by default for TreeView, which means if an item is not in the viewport, it probably didn't get an container.
   If you call GetContainerFromItem on a TreeView, the ItemContainerGenerator searches only the direct child objects of the TreeView.  So you need to recursively traverse the TreeView and child TreeViewItem objects.  A further complication is that if the TreeView virtualizes its items (you enable virtualization by setting the VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing property to true), the child items need to be created before you can check its data object.

Hope this will help.

Pls refer to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2010/02/23/finding-an-object-treeviewitem.aspx

Regards
Dipak

Comment: Thx for answering. I didn't enable virtualization and don't know how to remove it. but even if my treeview contains one item I get the bug. and I'm searching for an item in the direct child node so it's not the problem of recursivity.